# A problem on limit involving greatest integer function

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

If $$f(n)=\left[\sqrt{n}+\frac{1}{2}\right]$$ where $[\cdot]$ denotes the greatest integer function, then find the value of the limit $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac{2^{f(k)}+2^{-f(k)}}{2^{n}}\right).$$

My attempt: I tried to evaluate individual values of $f(n)$ for different values of n to get a pattern, e.g. $$f(1) = f(2)= 1,\quad  f(3) = f(4)= f(5) = f(6)= 2,\\ f(7) = f(8) = f(9) = f(10) = f(11) = f(12) = 3,\dots $$ 
but I feel there should be a generic way of handling this problem.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you interested in this other limit? $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac{2^{f(k)}+2^{-f(k)}}{2^{k}}\right)$$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2949570/find-sum-n-1-infty-frac2fn2-fn2n-where-fn-left-sqrt?noredirect=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have that
$$0\leq \frac{1}{2^{n}}\sum_{k=1}^n\left(2^{f(k)}+2^{-f(k)}\right)\leq
\frac{n\left(2^{f(n)}+1\right)}{2^{n}}\leq
\frac{n\left(2^{\sqrt{n}+\frac{1}{2}}+1\right)}{2^{n}}\to 0.$$
Therefore your limit is zero:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac{2^{f(k)}+2^{-f(k)}}{2^{n}}\right)=0.$$

Maybe you are interested in this other limit:
$$L_2:=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac{2^{f(k)}+2^{-f(k)}}{2^{k}}\right)$$
Then note that $\{f(n)\}_{n\geq 1}$ is an increasing sequence where the number $k$ appears $2k$ times.

Hence 
$$L_2=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(2^{k}+2^{-k}\right)\sum_{j=k(k-1)+1}^{k(k+1)}\frac{1}{2^j}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\sum_{i=(k-1)^2}^{k^2}\frac{1}{2^i}
+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\sum_{i=k^2+1}^{(k+1)^2-1}\frac{1}{2^i}\\
=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\sum_{i=(k-1)^2}^{k^2-1}\frac{1}{2^i}
+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\sum_{i=k^2}^{(k+1)^2-1}\frac{1}{2^i}
=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^i}
+\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^i}=2+1=3.$$

Comment: Heartiest thanks @Robert Z for the solution of the alternative question.

Comment: @MathsLearner You are welcome!!

Answer (score 1):

Use the fact that: $x-1<\big[x\big] \leq x$, you will find that $2^ {-\frac{1}{2}}+  2^{ -\frac{1}{2}-2n}<\left(\frac{2^{f(k)}+2^{-f(k)}}{2^{n}}\right)\leq 2^ \frac{1}{2}+  2^{ \frac{1}{2}-2n}$
And do the sommation...